# EXT JS 4.2.1 - Object does not support this property in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, extjs

**Overview**
I am working on the migration of an application from EXT JS 4.0 to 4.2.1. The requirement is to have the migrated app working in IE as well as Chrome frame enabled IE.

**Issue**
The app uses two custom components which were written for 4.0. Now, in IE - while trying to attach the events, there is an error saying "Object does not support this property".

In Chrome frame there is no error seen. We see that the error is happening in the EXT JS Debug all.js file where:
1. IE - uses dom.attachevent method
2. CF - uses addEventListener method

Now the input in the DOM while debugging the code was that we are getting an array of DOM object, instead of a DOM object in itself. (ie if I hardcoded dom[0].attachEvent, then we dont see the error).

**Request**
I am completely stuck as to how to approach this issue! Thank you in advance for any pointers to solving the issue. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, but in my case the problem was the creation of a triggerWrap DOM element that was a div, but in ExtJS 4.2.1 is a table element:

```
'<div id="{cmpId}-triggerWrap" class="{triggerWrapCls}" role="presentation">',
```

The id `-triggerWrap` was picked up by ExtJS code, that assumed the element was a table.

Maybe in your case it is also an incorrect element which is created and has the same id that ExtJS expects to be of a different element.